# toolkit getdefaulttoolkit crash the apps after press a button

Tags: java

//

```
 //System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");
            java.awt.Toolkit toolkit = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard clipboard = toolkit.getSystemClipboard();
            String result = null;``
            try {
                result = (String) clipboard.getData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor);
            } catch (Exception e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I set Headles to true it didnt work either
Thank you for your reply

Comment: What is the exception that you are getting?

Comment: Nothing in the lLogCat displayed the apps just crash and stiopped in getdefualtToolkit  after press paste button iam usjing JDK 9

Comment: That is an Android class, are you trying to access the clipboard on Android?

Comment: yes my android apps crash

Comment: Here, this should be able to help you: [Copy and Paste](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/copy-paste.html)

Comment: ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)FXActivity.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
it is carshing as well in the above code getSeystemSrvice?(CLPBOARD_SERVICE)

Comment: ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)FXActivity.getInstance().getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
it crash as well on the above code

Comment: What are the errors you are getting?